# Magento 2 - Override an xml file defined in the etc folder in a theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, xml

I am attempting to override the email templates for the `Aheadworks_Giftcard` extension. It seems that the email templates are defined in a `xml` file in the `etc` directory called `sample_email_templates.xml`.

`Aheadworks/Giftcard/etc/sample_email_templates.xml` snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sample_email_templates.xsd">
    <!-- todo: Need to be refactored to avoid data duplication. Difference between 'template_text' content in card image file name -->
    <template>
        <template_code>Christmas</template_code>
        <template_subject>You've been sent a gift from {{var sender_name}}</template_subject>
        <template_styles><![CDATA[img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    outline: none !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    background: #e1e1e1;
}]]></template_styles>
        <template_text><![CDATA[<table class="body-wrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; border-spacing: 0 !important; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; width: 100%; background: #e1e1e1; margin: 0; padding: 20px;">
    <tr style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>
        <td class="container first-container" style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; clear: both !important; display: block !important; max-width: 560px !important; background: #f5f5f5; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;">

            <!-- content -->
            <div class="content" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; display: block; max-width: 560px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; border-spacing: 0 !important; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <tr style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                        <td class="center" style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="center">

                            <p class="gift-card-cover" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;">
                                <img class="center" src="{{var card_image_base_url}}christmas.png"
```

I am not quite sure where to place the overridden `sample_email_templates.xml` with the updated email templates within the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Not seen the code of module in question, but one approach would be to create a custom module, extend the block that loads the xml-file and point to your custom xml template. Then set your preference for your block in your modules `di.xml`. Don´t forget to set the original modules name in sequence on your `module.xml`.